# Error No iqr handler for vector

Tags: boot

Sorry for my bad English, I've a problem during the boot of Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

When I boot the first option of the grub "Ubuntu", a black screen appears and

```
says: [ 0.004000] 1.55 No iqr handler for vector 
      [ 0.004000] 2.55 No iqr handler for vector
      [ 0.004000] 3.55 No iqr handler for vector
```

Or something like that and takes a long time to start the OS, then I can perfectly use it, my laptop is a Lenovo G50-45.
I have had problems with the privative drivers, really I'm a newbie in Linux, but this problem makes me annoying.

If you have a link in this forum o another please share me the results or if you know how to resolve it, IDK please.

Comment: Hi Rulo!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  This looks like a kernel issue to me.  Can you please upgrade (or downgrade) your kernel and see if it happens in a particular kernel version or try a mainline kernel to see if it's a kernel issue or a patch issue.

Comment: I've tried downgrading, I dont know if i done it well, I've restarted my lapton, and in advanced options I put a older version, appears 4.15.033 and I put 4.15.032 generic, and nothing happened. The error continues appearing, and other error with my Bluetooth... I start to get scared. :'c

Answer (score 0):

Now based on the situation for another user [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1234983) please try this following steps:

1. Open a terminal after your system boot with the key combinations of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>. then
2. Type `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` to open this file,
3. Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi,noaer"`, after editing do:

   - Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>: This will save and close the editor
4. Then run `sudo update-grub`, and reboot

Comment: Nothing happenes, It still jumping that error. I tried putting my iso in a virtualbox and works well. So IDK what to do :c